# How to update children content in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have the Issue.js, the IssueItems.js and the App.js which is the parent and I want to update the contents in Issue Items on click. Below is my code:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
         issues: [],
    }
  this.update_description= this.update_description.bind(this);
  }
  update_description(){
     this.setState({ issues:[
     {
      title: 'Issue 11'
     },
     ],
     })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="box-2">
            <h2> Issues </h2>
            <Issues className="Iss" issues={this.state.issues}/>
            </div>

    );
 }
}

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import IssueItem from './IssueItem';


class Issues extends Component {

  render() {
    let issueItems;
    if(this.props.issues){
      issueItems = this.props.issues.map(issue =>{
        return(
          <IssueItem key={issue.title} issue={issue} update_description = 
{this.props.update_description}/>
       );
      });
    }

    return (
      <div className="Iss" >
       {issueItems}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Issues;

import React, { Component } from 'react';



class IssueItem extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <li onClick = {this.props.update_description} type="circle" 
className="Iss">
         {this.props.issue.title}
     </li>
    );
  }
}

export default IssueItem;
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work? It doesn't give any error but it doesn't update the Issue title. In the initial state the issues are 5 with title from 01 to 05. I created them with componentWillMount()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never pass the update_description() method as a property in to your Issues component, so it can not be reached. If you change the render method of App.js to include the property it should work:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="box-2">
            <h2> Issues </h2>
            <Issues className="Iss" issues={this.state.issues} update_description={this.update_description}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```